# What is this kind of chain assignment and comparison in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

(Python 2.7 question)

I found a pattern similar to the following in a python codebase:

```
>>> a = b == 7
>>> a
True
>>> b
7
>>> a = b == -7
>>> a
False
>>> b
7
```

I'm looking for the terminology for this - I found some other answers that referred to (a = b = 7) as "chain assignment". What is the format (a = b == 7) called?

Comment: I don't think there's any fancy terminology for this...it's just assigning a variable to a boolean.

Comment: It'd be news to be if this type of assignment had a dedicated name. It's simply assigning the result of an expression to a name. A boolean expression / comparison in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`b == 7` is comparison for equality. The result of a comparison is a boolean value that is assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a normal assignment statement.  If you are ever curious about how a line of python is parsed, try the `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('a = b == 7'), annotate_fields=False)
"Module([Assign([Name('a', Store())], Compare(Name('b', Load()), [Eq()], [Num(7)]))])"
```

We can see that there is an equality comparison with `b` and `7`, and that result is used in an assignment to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an assignment of boolean expression to a variable:

```
 a    =      (b == 7)
#               ^ comparation expression that evaluate to True or False 
#     ^ assign the expression to a
```